# Multiple references with letter

Tags: macros, cite-package

I want to group the range of references together with letter of the alphabet (i.e. [A.1-A.5] instead [A.1][A.2][A.3] or [A.1, A.2, A.3] and I know that I should use \usepackage{cite} for it. Documment class is article.

I have a little makro for putting the letter of the alphabet to references:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{czech}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}

%%% Macro %%%
\makeatletter
\def\bibitem{\@lbibitem}
\def\@lbibitem#1{\stepcounter{\@listctr}\item[\@biblabel{\znak\the\value{\@listctr}}\hfill]\if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#1}{\znak\the\value{\@listctr}}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\zmena#1{\def\znak{#1}\setcounter{\@listctr}{0}\relax\ignorespaces }
\makeatother
\def\znak{A.} 
%%%%%%

\begin{document}
Bibliography test \cite{a, b, c}.

\begin{thebibliography}{A.999}
\bibitem{a} bib 1
\bibitem{b} bib 2
\bibitem{c} bib 3
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

But when I use it, usepackage cite do not function and it prints [A.1][A.2][A.3]
I need "letter prefix", becouse I must structure references to "my" (they have prefix A) and "other" (they have prefix B).

How do I do it correctly, please?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please also enlighten us as to the purpose of the `A` prefix.

Comment: I updated the question...

Comment: You probably shoould consider using `biblatex` for that.

Comment: biblatex has same effect, it prints [A.1, A.2, A.3] but I need [A.1-A.3] :-(